# Calculate a given number to a percentage between two given numbers

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to work out a percentage between two numbers by providing the number of which the percentage should be based (can't find this on Stack overflow - only percentage between two numbers).

Let me explain:

```
$start_number = 14700
$end_number = 14900


// This is the number to calculate a percentage for
// in this basic example this should come to 50%
$percentage_number = 14800
```

I know what I need to do but can't figure out how to write it:

*Where $start_number is 0%*

*And $end_number is 100%*

**$percentage_number = X%**

Comment: Your question is not clear at all..

Comment: Not getting your question can you explain??

Comment: `($percentage_number-$start_number)/($end_number-$start_number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$difference = $end_number - $start_number; // 200
$difference_from_start = $end_number - $percentage_number; // 100
$percentage = $difference_from_start / $difference; // 0.5 (50%)
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: @FriendlyCode Except this is 0 if `$percentage_number` is 14900.

Comment: This answers works well, I just need to reverse the percentage so it got higher with a higher number. $new_percentage = 1 - $percentage;

Answer (score 1):

Well this is quite simple:

```
$start_number = 14700;
$end_number = 14900;
$percentage_number = 14800;

$result = (($end_number - $percentage_number) * 100) / ($end_number - $start_number);

echo $result;
```

OUTPUT:

```
50
```

Answer (score 1):

I thik that the solution formula would be:

percentage = 100 * (percentage_number - start_number) / (end_number - start_number)

Answer (score 1):

In that case $percentage_number should not be less than $start_number else the percentage will calculated in negative.

You can use the below formula:

`( ($percentage_number - $start_number) / ($end_number - $start_number) ) * 100 ;`

Hope it'ill help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two numbers, 40 and 30.

30/40*100 = 75.
  So 30 is 75% of 40.

40/30*100 = 133. 
  So 40 is 133% of 30.

The percentage increase from 30 to 40 is:
  (40-30)/30 * 100 = 33%

The percentage decrease from 40 to 30 is:
  (40-30)/40 * 100 = 25%.

These calculations hold true whatever your two numbers.

In PHP

```
$oldFigure = 14;
$newFigure = 12.50;

$percentChange = (1 - $oldFigure / $newFigure) * 100;

echo $percentChange;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
diff = $end_number - $start_number

(diff is now = 200)

mid = $end_number - (your number) 

(mid is now = 100)

res = (mid / diff) * 100

(res is now = 50%)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the scale begins at `$start_number` and ends at `$end_number`, its size is `$end_number-$start_number`. If `$percentage_number` is in the scale, it's `$percentage_number-$start_number` units from the start into the scale. Therefore, the relative ratio in the scale being:

```
($percentage_number-$start_number)/($end_number-$start_number)
```

Multiply by 100 and you'll get the percentage.